# Downloading Sentinel-1 VH time-series for polygon

Tags: python, sentinel-1, sentinel-hub

```
    from sentinelhub import FisRequest, Geometry, CRS
    time_interval = (start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

    fis_request = FisRequest(layer=XXX,
                             geometry_list=[Geometry(feature['geometry'], CRS.WGS84)],
                             time=time_interval,
                             resolution=YYY)

    fis_data = fis_request.get_data()
```

I would like to average `VH` data for a polygon using the sentinelhub API. I am using the FisRequest API to do that but I am not sure what to specify for layer and resolution and if that is indeed the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistical API (FIS) is for sure the most convenient option.

I suggest you create a new layer in Configuration utility, choosing the data source to be Sentinel-1 GRD, then writing this in the Script window:

```
return [VV];
```

Resolution should be 20m.

Comment: thanks @Grega M. I realized that a `BANDS-S1-IW` layer already exists in the configuration. If instead of `return [VV];` I use `return [VV, VH];`, then the fis_request would contain `VV` in `C0` and `VH` in `C1` right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.